# Sorting in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new in XSLT and I want to transform my XML data into a HTML table and then sort the table on preis field : here is my code but it does not work. would you please tell me what is the problem in my code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>
          Hallo
        </h1>
        <table border="1">

          <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:sort select="preis" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>

        </table>  
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="artikel">
    <tr>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="name" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="lieferant" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="preis"/>
    </tr> 
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="name|lieferant|preis">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td> 
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and XML file:

```
<lieferungen>
  <artikel id="3526">
    <name>apfel</name>
    <lieferant>Fa. Krause</lieferant>
    <preis stueckpreis="true">8.97</preis>
  </artikel>
  <artikel id="7866">
    <name>Kirschen</name>
    <preis stueckpreis="false">10.45</preis>
    <lieferant>Fa. Helbig</lieferant>
  </artikel>
  <artikel id="3526">
    <preis stueckpreis="true">12.67</preis>
    <lieferant>Fa. Liebig</lieferant>
    <name>apfel</name>
  </artikel>
  <artikel id="7866">
    <preis stueckpreis="false">17.67</preis>
    <name>Kirschen</name>
    <lieferant>Fa. Krause</lieferant>
  </artikel>
  <artikel id="3627">
    <name>apfel</name>
    <lieferant>Fa. Mertes</lieferant>
    <preis stueckpreis="true">9.54</preis>
  </artikel>
  <artikel id="7866">
    <name>Kirschen</name>
    <lieferant>Fa. Hoeller</lieferant>
    <preis stueckpreis="false">16.45</preis>
  </artikel>
  <artikel id="7868">
    <preis>3.20</preis>
    <name>Kohl</name>
    <lieferant>Fa. Hoeller</lieferant>
  </artikel>
  <artikel id="7866">
    <name>Kirschen</name>
    <lieferant>Fa. Richard</lieferant>
    <preis stueckpreis="false">12.45</preis>
  </artikel>
  <artikel id="3245">
    <preis stueckpreis="false">15.67</preis>
    <name>Bananen</name>
    <lieferant>Fa. Hoeller</lieferant>
  </artikel>
  <artikel id="6745">
    <name>Kohl</name>
    <lieferant>Fa. Reinhardt</lieferant>
    <preis stueckpreis="false">3.10</preis>
  </artikel>
  <artikel id="7789">
    <name>Ananas</name>
    <preis stueckpreis="true">8.60</preis>
    <lieferant>Fa. Richard</lieferant>
  </artikel>
</lieferungen>
```

Comment: Without a sample of the input XML, the required output and actual output, how are we supposed to know what "doesn't work" means?

Comment: I meant that  price(number) should be sort  accesnding or descendind

Comment: Now you are making things even more confusing. Do you need ascending or descending? Again, without understanding what "does not work" means exactly, we can't help.

Comment: both of them do not work Oded

Comment: I am going to ask one last time for you to explain what "does not work" means exactly - provide samples of your XML, expected output and current output. If I don't see these coming within the next hour, I am voting to close this question.

Comment: The link is not accessible. Post the actual XML, like you did with the XSLT. Also the expected output and actual output.

Comment: at the end of my post you can see my XML file. i have a some fruits in XML format with Price i want to show this fruits in HTML table format using XSLT that this table is sorted(both ass. or dec.) on Price field but with my above code i can not do that  and i want to know which part of my code is not correct  .(some part of XML code is German language)

Comment: At the end of your post I can see a link to a file that I can't access. Describing what you have is not as helpful as you actually posting it.

Comment: So, where are the expected output XML sample and the actual output sample?

Comment: I explaind it Oded,It does not enough? How can I show my expected Output?I want to produce that

Comment: Are you really telling me you don't know what you want the result to look like??? Can you not  explain what "not working" means? Do you get any output? Errors? Something???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if I understood your question

BTW! The order of the child tags inside the article tag are not the same for all articles

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="lieferungen/artikel">
<xsl:sort select="preis" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
    <td>
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </td>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Outputs:

```
<td xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <artikel id="6745">
    <name>Kohl</name>
    <lieferant>Fa. Reinhardt</lieferant>
    <preis stueckpreis="false">3.10</preis>
</artikel>
</td>
<td xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <artikel id="7868">
    <preis>3.20</preis>
    <name>Kohl</name>
    <lieferant>Fa. Hoeller</lieferant>
  </artikel>
</td>
<td xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <artikel id="7789">
    <name>Ananas</name>
    <preis stueckpreis="true">8.60</preis>
    <lieferant>Fa. Richard</lieferant>
  </artikel>
</td>
...
...
<td xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <artikel id="7866">
    <preis stueckpreis="false">17.67</preis>
    <name>Kirschen</name>
    <lieferant>Fa. Krause</lieferant>
  </artikel>
</td>
```